# What the difference between (*T)(nil) and &T{}/new(T)? Golang

Tags: memory, memory-management, syntax, go

Could anybody explain what the subtle difference between these two notations: `(*T)(nil)/new(T)` and `&T{}`.

```
type Struct struct {
    Field int
}

func main() {
    test1 := &Struct{}
    test2 := new(Struct)
    test3 := (*Struct)(nil)
    fmt.Printf("%#v, %#v, %#v \n", test1, test2, test3)
    //&main.Struct{Field:0}, &main.Struct{Field:0}, (*main.Struct)(nil) 
}
```

Seems like the only difference of this one `(*T)(nil)` from other is that it returns nil pointer or no pointer, but still allocates memory for all fields of the Struct.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The two forms `new(T)` and `&T{}` are completely equivalent: Both allocate a zero T and return a pointer to this allocated memory. The only difference is, that `&T{}` doesn't work for builtin types like `int`; you can only do `new(int)`.

The form `(*T)(nil)` does *not* allocate a `T` it just returns a nil pointer to T. Your `test3 := (*Struct)(nil)` is just a obfuscated variant of the idiomatic `var test3 *Struct`.

Comment: if `(*T)(nil)` doesn't allocate memory, why I have access to its Struct's fields? `unsafe` shows the same values as if I just use new(T)

Comment: You don't have access.

Comment: Yes, you're right! It was autocompletion) Sorry for my noob questions, but if so, why the empty pointer still takes bytes?

Comment: What do you mean with "empty pointer still takes bytes"? The pointer itself needs space (typically 8 bytes) to be stored but it points to nowhere: there is no RAM allocated for the struct the pointer may point to.

Comment: Thank you I've heard what I wanted)