# What is the difference between new(T) and &T{}?

Tags: go

In Go, given struct type T, what is the difference between `new(T)` and `&T{}`?

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/210399/why-is-there-a-new-in-go

Comment: possible duplicate of [What the difference between (\*T)(nil) and &T{}/new(T)? Golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827871/what-the-difference-between-tnil-and-t-newt-golang)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending @Doug answer:

The two forms `new(T)` and `&T{}` are completely equivalent: Both allocate a zero T and return a pointer to this allocated memory. The only difference is, that &T{} doesn't work for [builtin types like](https://play.golang.org/p/tKr3d_fehQ) `int`; you can only do `new(int)`.

Comment: Yes, good point. &T{} is only for composite literals (i.e., structs, arrays, slices, and maps).

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference. According to [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals), they are equivalent.

> As a limiting case, if a composite literal contains no fields at all, it creates a zero value for the type. The expressions new(File) and &File{} are equivalent.